# Python: How to take screenshot/thumbnail/preview for URL as mobile device view?

Tags: python, mobile

I have a question.

I am looking for a solution for taking screenshot for both desktop view and mobile device (like iPhone) view.

You know some sites automatically displays mobile version of the page.

For example, http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ does the job currently and I want to do the similar thing, i.e. taking screenshot or viewing thumbnail of both desktop view and mobile device view of the page.

I also found http://grabz.it/api/python/grabzitclient.aspx, but it's not free.

In addition, instead of taking screenshot and save to somewhere, is there anyway I can load the site in iframe and save the disk usage? Is there anyway I can scale the content inside the iframe to make it look like a thumbnail image? (In this approach, I think it's impossible to load content inside iframe as mobile view, is this correct?)

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Please raise your second question as a separate question as the two are quite distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for the screenshot issue is to find an emulator for the mobile device(s) that you are targeting - I know that the Android developer kit includes a number of such and a quick Google suggests that there is a Googleplex of them out there for iPhone many free.